# Timeline in iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sharekit, facebook-timeline

I use ShareKit in most of my apps, but would like to add Timeline features into my app.  Like how spotify will automatically post songs you listen to on timeline.  Would this be something that could be added to my ShareKit implementation?

Comment: ShareKit has timeline ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. ShareKit has no timeline view. You have to do it on your own.